# How can i add email/jabber notification to xmobar status bar?

Tags: xmonad

I using xmonad+xmobar on my computer. I am missing notification on the status bar. May'be was way to integrate it's or ready plugin for this. Any ideas?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmobar#Gmail_integration How about this?

Comment: I found it https://gist.github.com/travitch/3707046

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to deploy a system tray in the status bar.

You may use one of these:

- trayer: https://github.com/sargon/trayer-srg
- stalonetray: http://stalonetray.sourceforge.net/
- ...